# Printing a text line containing the target word

Tags: python, string, txt

I want to find the exact line when I input the desired word. For example, if, in a text file, there are 50 lines and the word 'mirror' is somewhere on the 26th line, is it possible to print the whole line? the basic code is written below which should work, but it doesn't.

```
input_text = input("TYPE:")
file = "Library.txt"

with open(file, "r") as txtFile:
    for line in txtFile:
        if input_text in txtFile.read():
            print(line)

        else:
            print("not found!")
```

Comment: Use `if input_text in line`, not `if input_text in txtFile.read()`.

Comment: Try removing the `.read()` call. When you iterate over a file object with `for`, the line has already been read and you can just treat `line` as a string containing the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input_text = input("TYPE:")
file = "library.txt"

with open(file, "r") as txtFile:
    lines = txtFile.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if input_text in line:
            print(line)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly fine. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try [`readlines()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html?highlight=readlines#io.IOBase.readlines)(or directly file descriptor) in combination with [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) to obtain the line and set it to start at `1` so you get the exact line instead of manually incrementing it by 1 (`enumerate() starts at 0`):

```
# without readlines()
with open(file, "r") as txtFile:
    for line_num, line in enumerate(txtFile, start=1):
        if input_text in line:
            print(line_num, line)

        else:
            print("not found!")

# with readlines()
with open(file, "r") as txtFile:
    for line_num, line in enumerate(txtFile.readlines(), start=1):
        if input_text in line:
            print(line_num, line)

        else:
            print("not found!")
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `if input_text in line` instead of `if input_text in txtFile.read()`.
Also you can set a flag if the word is found. If it's not, it will print "not found", like this:

```
with open(file, "r") as txtFile:
    found = False

    for line in txtFile:
        if input_text in line:
            print(line)
            found = True
            
    if not found: 
        print("not found!")
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment!